# Laravel Multiple Files upload

Tags: laravel, file-upload

I need to upload image file into an array, I have no idea how laravel can get my files belong to the id when using `foreach` to read them.

Below is my blade code, I had multiple text and file

```
<textarea name="item[{{$item_row}}][description]"  placeholder="Description" class="form-control mb-1"  rows="5"></textarea>
<input type="file" name="item[{{$item_row}}][file_image]"/>
```

And I have no idea how the controller stores the files from `foreach`

```
foreach($data['item'] as $k => $v){
   //read files here
  $v['image'] =  $request->file('item['. $k . '][file_image]')->store('downloadfile');
 // or
 $v['image'] =  $request->file($v['file_image'])->store('downloadfile');
}
```

The code does not store the files

Comment: can you add entire method that you're trying?

and also you're missing `multiple` attribute in input

Comment: add `multiple` attribute in input type file